# Google Chrome Downgrade

Tags: google-chrome, installation, version-control

I want to Downgrade my Google chrome version 37 to chrome version 35 for some purposes. I've been disabling the Google Update Services from `services.msc` and downloaded a stand alone versions but its still updating.

Also every time I download a full offline installer and run it. It tries connecting to my internet and check for updates. If it found some updates, it will install the updated version of it.

I also been through `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update "Update{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}"` and set the values to zero and I also tried to add Google update administrative template on local group editor. But it is still updating.

Can someone help me?

Comment: A simple search shows how to prevent chrome from updating http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-can-i-disable-google-chrome-auto-update

Comment: @Ramhound I've done that. I've been through _HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update "Update{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}_. I also tried adding administrative templates to the local group policy editor and all. but its still updating whenever I install a chrome version 35

Comment: Another method (less impressive than a native fix maybe but works as well) is to have a firewall program block the updater.

Comment: Various firewall programs exist for this purpose. Windows firewall may suffice nowadays, but ZoneAlarm will work and others as well.

Comment: Mac can use 'Little Snitch' to firewall-block the updaters if you are using that platform.

Answer (score 2):

The program that is doing that is deletable. Install chrome while offline. Look in the directory where it is located and delete the file. I have multiple versions of chrome installed in different accounts on my machine and it works fine.

The file is:

```
GoogleUpdate.exe
```

Found in this folder location:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Update
```

Comment: It works to create a VM (VirtualBox or VMWare, etc...) and create accounts for each version you wish to install.

Comment: I literally have Chrome 01, Chrome 02, ..., Chrome 28..., etc.. as separate user accounts in the VM. Each one with a different Chrome version installed.