# How to update chrome browser without uninstall ( for error 1 )?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, updates, auto-updates

I'm using chrome **Version 33.0.1750.154** and i cant update my browser to new version. I have noticed that the following error in => About Google Chrome Tab

> Version 33.0.1750.154
>    Update failed (error: 1)

And when i tried to resolve this issue most of the suggestions told to re install new version.

[Google support](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/111996?hl=en) suggests to re locate the configuration files.But i'm not sure to how to achieve this.

Summary of Question

How to update chrome browser without uninstall ( for error 1 )?

Comment: On which operative system run your chrome? You can search the default location of that files and their names. After that, you can search that filenames on your hard disk to see where they really are. BTW one of the suggestion of the google support is to uninstall and reinstall it...

Comment: Windows 7 operating system

Comment: Why don't you just uninstall it, choosing to keep your user profile, and reinstall it.  This seems the simplest way to solve your problem since you don't know where your configuration files are.

Comment: yes.I agree with you.But i want to just confirm is there any alternate solutions to solve this issue without uninstall and really this would be helpful if you guide how to relocate those file and where to kept those files?.

Comment: I read a question yesterday where the poster wanted to know how to stop Chrome from updating. The answer was to delete GoogleUpdate.exe - http://superuser.com/a/810095/58026 Could something be wrong with you GoogleUpdate.exe file? Funny, how everyone has different scenarios to deal with.

Comment: On your computer, open Chrome.
Press the Alt+F key.
Click the Help Option.
Click Update Google Chrome. 
Click Relaunch.
If you don't see this button, you're on the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a problem with GoogleUpdate.

The simplest answer is to allow Chrome to log into google and save all your settings, including bookmarks and extensions and such.  (In the settings screen you can tell it to connect)

Before you connect, use the button right below that to decide what you want backed up.  You can exclude browsing and download histories and just keep bookmarks and extensions, or whatever you choose.

You can create a new google (gmail) account for just this one thing if you don't already have one..

Then give it some time to do the synchronization.

You can watch in task manager to see when the network traffic tapers off as it finishes.

After that, go into settings and tell it to disconnect.

Don't uninstall Chrome.

Download a new copy of Chrome from http://chrome.google.com

Close Chrome.

If task manager shows leftover chrome.exe processes, you can either reboot or open an administrator CMD window and issue the command

```
Taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
```

Then run the new Chrome install file.

It will automatically reinstall the Updater software.

After it is up and running, go back to settings and tell it to connect to the Google account, and it will re-synchronize your settings, bookmarks, extensions, etc. - whatever you told it to synchronize in the first place.

After that you can decide whether or not you want to continue to allow it to keep you sync'd to Google or not.

You are free to disconnect and never use that Google account again if you wish.

One significant advantage of continuing to keep it connected is, if you have more than one computer, to allow that google account to keep your bookmarks and extensions synchronized across all of them.  Including anything Android.